# Multiple select list with actionListeners?

Tags: java, jsf, tree, components

I want to achieve the following:

- It should be possible to create entries, and these entries (Strings) should be displayed as a list. A list entry should be selectable (with listener method on each entry) by a single click, without holding any keyboard buttons. Also clicking an already selected entry should deselect it.
- Also, an entry should get a dimension, which will specify the number of subentries. These should be visible by some kind of expand button before the entry. Again, subentries should also be multiple selectable.

Are there components that already provide such a feature? If not, what should I look into to build such a component?

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) component. Good luck with that.

Comment: no I'm not looking into any swing components (JEE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the GWT Tree Cell component by now:
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree

Comment: How do you plan to integrate get and jsf? Could you share that here in your answer? Seems to me like it's a lot of work though.

Comment: I will update my answer if I chose this at the end and find out how to integrate them. Probably you could mix the two by having GWT modules run within JSF pages. The JSF page would be generated on the server and the GWT module would run on the client once the rendered page is downloaded. Somehow...

Comment: Ok I'm just switching over to use plain GWT without jsf. And I also found a component that does what I requested: http://code.google.com/p/checkable-tree/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any component that does that.

Having said that, [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [tree component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) that allows for custom markup for the hierarchical elements, it may be worthy look into.