# How to display nested checkboxes?

Tags: java, jsf, gwt, tree, components

I am displaying a lot of boolean values on a page as checkboxes with labels.
For some of them, a "checkbox object" can itself contain several other sublevels of checkboxes.

So I want to display them as some kind of Tree: when selecting a checkbox that has subboxes, they should only then be displayed. when deselecting the most upper checkbox, all nested boxes/entries should disappear.

How could I achieve this with JSF or GWT?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a case for the [OmniFaces tree component](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/components/tree.xhtml), which I cited in an answer of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780466/multiple-select-list-with-actionlisteners).

Comment: Also you can use GXT checkbox tree http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:checkboxtree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a typical usage of the GWT CellTree,  take a look to the [ShowCase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) example.